# Following an old Rabbi's Pesak

Tags: halacha, rabbis, posek-psak-decisor-ruling

Let's say you asked your old rabbi a question and he answered you, but now let's say you have lost contact with him. Do you still have to follow this pesak or can you change?

Comment: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:XbiAHZnbDjkJ:rabbikaganoff.com/archives/1520+&cd=25&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us I think the answer may be in here. I hope to summarize it later.

Comment: If I see the title correctly, this is about the concept of "lo bashamayim hi" which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Are you asking about a question you asked a long time ago when he was your rabbi and now he's not?  Or are you saying that you asked him a question after he stopped being your rabbi (maybe you ran into him somewhere)?

Comment: @MonicaCellio He used to be my rabbi and now is not.

Comment: @HachamGabriel see section headed by "How long does the ruling remain binding?"

Comment: @ShmuelBrill huh?

Comment: @HachamGabriel search the page (mentioned by doubleAA ) for the words "How long does the ruling remain binding?"

Comment: @ShmuelBrill Yes that's what I was referring to. I'm a little busy now to write it up right, so if you (or anyone else) want to, that's ok by me.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Did you ask the rabbi a long time ago? Did you happen to bump into him and ask him the question? Do you live in his community? What happened and what are the circumstances?

Answer (score 1):

If you change rabbi/shita/chasidis - you take on the laws of the new.

EG - ashkenaz woman marries sfardi - eats rice on pesach
Askenaz turns sefardi - change your tefilin
If your new rebbi only holds R Tam lechumra, you should not hold it lekula in his town.

If you learn a sugya/halacha or anything wrong, or differntly later - you change.  Judaism is a living organism

Comment: Do you have an halachic source for the assertion that one can, let alone should, change his practices when he change rabbis or _chasiduyos_?

Comment: @Jon - Regarding Judaism being a "living organism," I heard a shiur by R' Moshe Weinberger (who is from Aish Kodesh Woodmere) on Orot (by Rav Kook) that reminded me of this.